# jQuery Promises and Deferred, confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred

I thought I'd finally got my head around promises but it seems I'm straying a little.

Can anyone put me out of my misery and explain what I'm doing wrong here:

`t010 = {
      myGet: function(url) {
        var result = new $.Deferred();
        result.resolve(ajaxRequest(url));
      }
    }`

Which is then called by my main method as so:

`$.when(t010.myGet(seatId), t010.myGet(roomId)).then(function(d1, d2) { 
  console.log(d1);
}`

I just console log undefined every time.

I think what i'm trying to achieve is fairly obvious, I want to call myGet twice and when both are complete do something with the results.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the promise to use `$.when`

```
t010 = {
  myGet: function(url) {
    var result = new $.Deferred();
    result.resolve(ajaxRequest(url));

    return resolve.promise();
  }
}
```

but that resolves the promise immediately, passing back the result of the `ajaxRequest` function, which is probably `undefined` at that time?
But, the `ajaxRequest` already looks like it returns a promise, you can return it directly

```
t010 = {
  myGet: function(url) {
    return ajaxRequest(url));
  }
}
```

assuming your ajax function looks something like

```
function ajaxRequest(url) {

    return $.ajax({
        url : url
    });

}
```

Comment: I understand yeah, I think my problem lies in the ajaxRequest function I'm having to use as it returns `return $.ajax(defaults).promise().then(function (data) { try { return JSON.parse(data); } catch (e) { return data; }` hence why I'm getting nothing.

Comment: You can't return the data from from the function like that, as it's async, all you really need is `return $.ajax(defaults);`, and then do the `then()` (wich could be `done()`) function where you're calling it, `ajaxRequest(url).done(function(data) {});` etc. and you can wrap multiple of those in `$.when` etc.

Comment: I have no control over the function that returns that annoyingly (at least not just now), so i'm having to use it as is, I take it this isn't going to work without changing the ajax function then?

Comment: It should, looks like your ajax function already returns a promise, so just try chaining on a handler and see what happens, like `ajaxRequest(url).always(function() { console.log(arguments) });` and see what it does ?

Comment: thank you, moving the ajax function around and using it like in your original answer worked perfectly in the end!